# MySQL database table not inserting data

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-2

I have a MySQL database table named login which stores user information and login details. The table has been working well (inserting, updating and selecting) but from yesterday,the table is not inserting data from my php codeigniter scripts but its selecting and updating.

Also, when I insert a row manually (in phph Myadmin), its inserting well. The table has only 470 rows and its using InnoDB ingine and its 192KB. What could be the problem? The database is on a shared host. Here is the php code

```
function insertUser($pfNo, $fName, $mName, $lName, $email, $username, $encPassword, $userType,$preuniYear, $salt, $creationDate){
        $data = array(
            'pfNo' => $pfNo,
            'fName' => $fName,
            'mName' => $mName,
            'lName' => $lName,
            'email' => $email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $encPassword,
            'userType' => $userType,
            'year' => $preuniYear

        );
        $query1 = $this->db->insert('login', $data);

        $data = array(
            'username' => $pfNo,
            'creationDate' => $creationDate
        );
        $query3 = $this->db->insert('systemdetails', $data);


        if ($query1 && $query3) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }`
```

Comment: Duplicate user names + unique index?

Comment: The pfNo field is the primary key and username is unique. There is no duplicates. Also everything has been working fine till yesterday when I could insert a user.

Comment: There must be extended error info in the class you are using. See what it says.

Comment: Usually when active record fails you have an error on $this->db->_error_message(); you should try accessing it when it is not so you have a more descriptive error on your issue.